# Kubuntu says no disk space available, although there is lots of space

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

I have a 60 GB partition where Kubuntu 18.04.1 is installed. Yesterday when I tried to upgrade to 18.10, I was told that there wasn't sufficient disk space, although I am certainly sure there is.

`df -h` shows:

```
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           389M  6.3M  383M   2% /run
/dev/sda7        65G   64G   1G   98% /
tmpfs           1.9G   38M  1.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6130
/dev/sda2        95M   30M   66M  32% /boot/efi
tmpfs           389M     0  389M   0% /run/user/119
tmpfs           389M   12K  389M   1% /run/user/1000`
```

Comment: What does `df -h` show?

Comment: `df -h` shows that the root partition is 99% full, but `du -cha /` says that only 15GB of 60 GB is used

Comment: Your disk is probably divided into two or more partitions, and the OS is complaining that one of these partitions is full.  The command you used will not show this, but `df -h` will...

Comment: what the output of: sudo lsof | grep deleted

Comment: You have exactly 1GB of space, by the way, my guess is you need more than 1GB of disk space here.  `/dev/sda7        65G   64G   1G   98% /` is the relevant line

Comment: Oh don't worry, I solved it by cleaning `/var/log`. `df -h` shows 22% now.